How to fix android emulator cant be selected?
(https://i.sstatic.net/ZLL2hs0m.png))I’m having an issue with my emulator: I can't select any of the emulators.
and i am not running multiple emulators with the same AVD.
I’ve tried deleting and recreating the emulator, but the problem persists. It still looks like it does in the video here https://t.me/cscornersunitarai/5385 and i just keep getting this error
INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\Johoo\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-35.1.20.db, detection is enabled for process: 20428
INFO | Android emulator version 35.1.20.0 (build_id 12234392) (CL:N/A)
INFO | Graphics backend: gfxstream
INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\Johoo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-31\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: c009:183d:2a02:0:d0ef:173d:2a02:0 (2x)
ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD
ERROR | is an experimental feature.
ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.
INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\Johoo\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-35.1.20.db, detection is enabled for process: 25000
INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO | IPv4 server found: 192.168.100.1
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: d0ef:173d:2a02:0:d0ef:173d:2a02:0
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: d0ef:173d:2a02:0:d0ef:173d:2a02:0 (2x)
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: d0f5:173d:2a02:0:d0ef:173d:2a02:0
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: d0f5:173d:2a02:0:d0ef:173d:2a02:0 (2x)
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: e8fb:173d:2a02:0:d0ef:173d:2a02:0
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: e8fb:173d:2a02:0:d0ef:173d:2a02:0 (2x)
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: c009:183d:2a02:0:d0ef:173d:2a02:0


is this better?

thanx this much better
